# postgres table - Does it require partitioning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-9.3

We have a usecase where in a year we can be storing 600 MB of data (worst case) in a postgres table.
It is a very small table. Does it require any partitioning to be made scalable. Appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This amount of data will comfortably fit in RAM. Maybe if you were accumulating 600GB of data a year it would be worth thinking about.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I checked RAM size in one of the nodes where postgres is installed. We have only around 5 GB free RAM left. In that case, I believe it would be safer to have a partitioned table with each partition not exceeding 1.5~2 GB max. Appreciate any insights!

Comment: No. Almost certainly not. Don't just randomly reach for features because you don't know what you're doing yet.

Comment: Certainly this is not for the initial use case I mentioned. I was trying to understand under which use case, a partitioned table is required based upon RAM availability.